# Middle of a linked list bug

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I write a function to print the middle of a singly linked list, but when the list length is odd, it is not printing it (does not print anything just blank space), and when the list length is even, it is printing the mid (sum of the node, which is correct).

I have the following code:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};
 
Node* head = NULL;

void insert_element2(int x);
void mid_list(Node* head);

int main() {

    insert_element2(1);
    insert_element2(2);
    insert_element2(3); //etc 


    mid_list(head);

    return 0;
}


void insert_element2(int x) {
    Node* temp1 = new Node();
    temp1->value = x;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) 
        head = temp1;
    else {
        Node* temp2 = head;
        while(temp2->next != NULL) {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp1;
    }
}


void mid_list(Node* head) {
    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp2 =  head;

    while (temp1->next != NULL) {  **// When i change "temp->next" with "temp" is acting opposite(even/odd)**
        temp1 = temp1->next->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    cout << temp2->value;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it will print the 'middle'? I mean you are not searching for the middle of the list at any point.

Comment: Need to check both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through the logic for your example of an odd-sized list:

- Upon entry to `mid_list()`, `head` is the `value=1` node, and `temp1` and `temp2` are set to `head`.  Note that you are NOT checking `head` for `NULL`, so your code will fail if the list is empty, but that is not the case in this example.
- On the 1st loop iteration, `temp1->next` is not `NULL`, so `temp1` gets set to `temp1->next->next` which is the `value=3` node, and `temp2` gets set to `temp2->next` which is the `value=2` node.
- On the 2nd loop iteration, `temp1->next` is `NULL`, so the loop breaks, and the `value=2` node gets printed (not a blank space, like you claim). So far, so good.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/sjpOoT)

Now, let's step through the logic for an even-sized list:

- Upon entry to `mid_list()`, `head` is the `value=1` node, and `temp1` and `temp2` are set to `head`.
- On the 1st loop iteration, `temp1->next` is not `NULL`, so `temp1` gets set to `temp1->next->next` which is the `value=3` node, and `temp2` gets set to `temp2->next` which is the `value=2` node.
- On the 2nd loop iteration, `temp1->next` is not `NULL`, so `temp1` gets set to `temp1->next->next` which is `NULL`, and `temp2` gets set to `temp2->next` which is the `value=3` node.
- On the 3rd loop iteration, `temp1` is `NULL` so accessing `temp1->next` is *undefined behavior* and the code fails.

So, to fix this, you need to change your loop to something more like this instead:

```
void mid_list(Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return;

    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp2 = head;

    while (temp1->next != NULL) {
        temp1 = temp1->next->next;
        if (temp1 == NULL) break;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    cout << temp2->value;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/35fyeN)

Or:

```
void mid_list(Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return;

    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp2 = head;

    while ((temp1 != NULL) && (temp1->next != NULL)) {
        temp1 = temp1->next->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    cout << temp2->value;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/LOvLjs)

Depending on which "middle" node you are actually interested in when iterating an even-sized list - the node to the left or the right of the mid-point.

Comment: i figure it out by your first comment and helped me to fix it and understand it, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are looking for the middle node. The next snippet does the trick:

```
void mid_list(Node* head) 
{
    Node* temp1 = head;
    
    auto nodeCount = 0u;
    while (temp1->next != nullptr) // walk through nodes if exists
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        ++nodeCount; //count valid nodes
    }

    temp1 = head; //reset the temp
    for (auto ii=0u; nodeCount / 2 > ii; ++ii ) // walk to the middle node from the head
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    if (nullptr != temp1) // sanity check
        std::cout << temp1->value;
}
```

For odd number of entries it is a true middle, for even it is either the node before (if you start counting from 0) or the node right after the "middle" index (if start from 1).

Comment: If the list is empty, `head` will be `nullptr` so `while (temp1->next != nullptr)` will fail with *undefined behavior*. To count all of the nodes, you need to use `while (temp1 != nullptr)` instead.

Comment: You're right, but the point of my answer was that there is another approach to find the middle node.

Comment: @Suthrio "*there is another approach to find the middle node*" - true, although multiple iterations should be avoided when a single iteration will suffice, especially for large lists. Granted, the OP's example is using a short list.  A variation of your answer would be to make `insert_element2()` keep track of how many nodes have been inserted, so that `mid_list()` doesn't have to count them at all. Then your `for` loop can be used by itself as a single iteration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course, there is a point of keeping the count of nodes during insert/remove operations of nodes, especially for large lists, since `mid_list` will be executed much faster as we don't need to check two times indirected values on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is one bug in your code, in while condition you must check "temp1->next" as you are pointing to its next inside the loop ,in case temp->next is NULL then temp1->next->next will be undefined.The code below will work fine:

```
    void mid_list(Node* head) {
    Node* temp1 = head;
    Node* temp2 =  head;

    while (temp1!=NULL && temp1->next != NULL) {  // here I have modified this line.
       temp1 = temp1->next->next;
       temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    cout << temp2->value;
    }
```